# while running my first network , peer chaincode instatiate hang

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

- peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P 'OR    ('\''Org1MSP.peer'\'','\''Org2MSP.peer'\'')'

while try to run my first network my program got hang here everytime

Comment: What do you mean by hang?  And how/where are you running this command?  Can you provide more detail about your env?

Comment: finally, I got it but i don't know what happened wrong

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in docs "The instantiation of the Node.js chaincode will take roughly a minute. The command is not hanging; rather it is installing the fabric-shim layer as the image is being compiled." Ref : http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html

Comment: for me it has taken hours and not yet finished.